# Convert Form Post to Querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, query-string, aspdotnetstorefront

I am working in ASPDotNetStorefront on an XML package (largely irrelivant). Basically I have a form with a bunch of fields and a button that 'submits' the form. I would actually like to have the button convert the values of the fields into a querystring and then perform a GET instead of a POST.

I would imagine that I could do something like this with JavaScript, perhaps jQuery, but I'm not sure how I would do that. Ideally, I would like a simple function I could call.

I should note that I'm using ASP.Net and I only want to convert the actual values of the fields to a query string, not any state information. This is for a search form.

Comment: Can you not just change the form to use GET instead with the `method="GET"` attribute, or why do you want to do this?

Comment: None of the solutions saying to just convert the form to a `GET` method worked because this page is hosted in an ASP.Net solution, and thus has VIEWSTATE and other stuff in the POST that just won't fit in the URL, nor do I need it there. I didn't know this was an option though, so I'll keep it in my back pocket for a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx?Name=" +
this.txtName.Text + "&LastName=" +
this.txtLastName.Text);
```

in WebForm2.aspx you can do like this

```
for (int i =0;i < Request.QueryString.Count;i++)
{
Response.Write(Request.QueryString[i]);
}
```

for jquery you can use AJAX to send data between pages. Here is the sample code
This is the best article i have found [Using jQuery for AJAX in ASP.NET : codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17203/Using-jQuery-for-AJAX-in-ASP-NET)
example of using AJAX

```
<div style="width:350px">
    <div style="background:#CCC"> <a href="#" id="editName">Edit</a></div>
    <div id="divView"><asp:literal id="litName" runat="server"/></div>
    <div id="divEdit" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    
var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'ChangeName.aspx',
                after: function(response) {
                    $("div#divView").html(response).show();
                    $("div#divEdit").empty().hide();
            $("a#editName").show(); 
                }
            };
            //bind to form's onsubmit event
            $("form#ChangeName").ajaxForm(options);
```

Example without AJAX.Simple Javascript with Query String

```
<script lang=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
function testQueryStrings()
{
window.location = “search.aspx?q=abc&type=advanced”;
}
</script>

<input type=”button” id=”btn” value=”Test Query Strings” onclick=”testQueryStrings()” />
```

for search.aspx

```
<script lang=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
var qrStr = window.location.search;
var spQrStr = qrStr.substring(1);
var arrQrStr = new Array();
// splits each of pair
var arr = spQrStr.split(‘&’);
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
// splits each of field-value pair
var index = arr[i].indexOf(‘=’);
var key = arr[i].substring(0,index);
var val = arr[i].substring(index+1);

// saves each of field-value pair in an array variable
arrQrStr[key] = val;
}

document.write(“<h1>Search parameter: “+arrQrStr["q"]+”. Extra parameter: “+arrQrStr["type"]+”</h1>”);
```

Comment: Baring something more efficient, I'm going to end up hand-coding this using a pattern similar to what you have here. What you suggested doesn't work for me. `onclick="window.location.href = 'searchadv.aspx?SearchTerm=' + SearchTerm.value; return(false);"`

Comment: Wonderful. I ended up using nearly exactly what you had for Example without AJAX.Simple Javascript with Query String. I actually created a routine that will check to see if each parameter value differs from the default before including it, but what you've demonstrated here is exactly what I needed. I like the routine you built too.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/Action',
    type: 'GET',
    data: $('#formId').serialize()
})
```

using:

[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[jQuery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="get">
```

With (since you tagged this jQuery):

```
jQuery('input[type=submit]').click(function () { this.form.method = 'GET'; });
```

… but forms that *might* go to bookmark-able data or *might* make significant changes sound like they would be confusing to the user (and I can't think of any other reason to switch from post to get on the fly in end user controls).

If you always want to GET data, then you should modify the source sent to the browser instead of twiddling the DOM on the fly with JS.

Comment: I received a Url Too Long message when I tried this. All sorts of __EVENTTARGET information was included in the URL.

Comment: For your explanation of how this would affect the bookmarks and other navigation elements and showing a simple jQuery...+1.

Comment: @cjbarth — Then you need to find a way to compress the data (look up tables, shorter key names, expressing numbers in base 16 instead of base 10, etc) and/or remove data you don't need.

Comment: That is the point, I don't know how to get jQuery or any other automated process to use only the fields I need in the querystring. Therefore I just had to write my own JavaScript function to build a querystring manually. If you have insight on this matter I'd be very interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you just need to change the `method` attribute of your `<form>` tag in your HTML.

If you don't have direct control over the markup that your .NET component generates, you can always manipulate the `<form>` tag and set the attribute with JavaScript when the page loads.

Or, you can bind a click event to the form's submit button, and cancel the event (by returning `false` for example), and do a `GET` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could just se `<form method="GET">` instead of `<form method="POST">`. No Javascript needed (unless you do not want to refresh the page).